# Git seperating projects into multiple sub project

Tags: git, project

I am new to Git. I am doing a client-server model project. My client side codes are in HTML, CSS, JS and my server side codes are in c++. Even though I am writing some Interface works in Python. Also, I am keeping configuration files, supporting tables and demo Flat File tables.

I don't how to structure this project in Git. What is the Feature used to do this in Git? I don't know how to start? What is the Directory structure should I use for this project? I have a basic idea of the Directory structure for this project. I give it here.

Please tell me what is the problem with this Directory structure if there exist? How can I update the Directory structure and version control to keep the project well versed?

I hope the answer of the question will be more helpful for a fresher working in a StartUp company.
My model of directory structure is,

```
+ Project
--- + client
------ + css
------ + js
--- + server
------ + libs
------ + exe
--- + Interface
------ + libs
------ + server
------ + client
--- + configuration
------ + App
----------[App Tables]
------ + Example
----------[Demo Tables]
```

How to configure Git for the recommended model? What is the feature in git to add sub git for `client`, `server`, `interface` and `data`?

Comment: You probably just need one git repo at the project level.

Answer (score 0):

Github does not allow to make empty folders. So try creating a file in a directory then delete the file.

Please see this link for more details

> https://github.com/KirstieJane/STEMMRoleModels/wiki/Creating-new-folders-in-GitHub-repository-via-the-browser